# Which ports do I need to forward for my ubuntu server?

Tags: server, webserver

Just set up a Trusty Tahr Ubuntu server(14.04.1), and have the server's static internal IP address (I think -- I have no idea how to test that it has been done successfully) and now I'd like to be able to access my server from the internet.

The server will be used for deploying django webapps with nginX.

I know I need to port forward, and I know *how* to port forward, I just don't know:

- what port to forward,
- or what range of ports to forward,
- or what criteria I should use for selecting a port to forward.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this at a home network?  If so, the 'static ip' is only internal - your public IP can always change.  It also depends what you want your server to be doing - is it a web server?  Media streaming server?  What all are you doing on it?  (Voting to close as Unclear until you provide clarifications)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? what kind of server are you trying to forward? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: @ Fabby I thought Trusty Tahr was the alias for the version 14.04.1, my mistake.  I will amend the post

Comment: @ Thomas W. home network, and yeah, that's a good point.  I should clarify I meant internally static, but still I have no idea how to test if I was successful.  LEMP server to deploy a django webapp.  Thanks for the guidance, updating now.

Comment: From the sound of the question... I am going to say forward port 80 (external) to port 80 of your webserver.  It really doesn't sound like you are looking to setup SSL (this sounds very simplistic).  In reality this completely depends on how you configure django and nginx.

Comment: How do i know that my server is listening on port 80?

Comment: @user3888177: The version number is a detail.  What kind of server?  VPN/web/ssh/Cluster/Oracle/MySQL/FTP/???  What kind of fixed IP?  What is the IP addressing scheme etc.  Your question is unclear. Please amend...

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward port 80 and port 8080 (alternative for port 80) so you can access your web server. You can forward ports like 21 (if you want to have access to ftp from outside world) and 22 (access to ssh).